# Why do I get warning 'Too few arguments to function' even though the update process is success on database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So here is the error :

> Message: Too few arguments to function Admin::edit_item(), 0 passed in
>   .. exactly 1 expected

```
/*
   * Edit Item
   */
   public function edit_item($id) {
     // Validate Rules
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name','Item Name','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[30]');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('price','Price','trim|required|is_natural_no_zero');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[500]');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','Quantity','trim|required|is_natural_no_zero');

     // Get Item Details
     $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($id);


     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
       // Load view
       $data['main_content'] = 'admin_edit_item';
       $this->load->view('layouts/main_admin', $data);
     }
     else
     {
       if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0) {
         // If There Is No Image Uploaded
         $product_update = $this->Product_model->update_item();

         if (!$product_update)
         {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('failed_edit_item', 'The Item Failed To Be Edited');
           redirect('admin/edit_item');
         }
         else
         {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('success_edit_item', 'The Item Is Successfully Edited');
           redirect('admin/edit_item');
         }
       }
       else
       {
         // Update The Database
         $this->Product_model->update_item();
         $product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');

         // Set Config For Uploading Image
         $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/product/';
         $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
         $config['max_size']             = 10000;
         $config['max_width']            = 225;
         $config['max_height']           = 225;
         $config['file_name']            = $product_id;

         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $this->upload->overwrite = true;

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
         {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('failed_edit_item', 'The Item Failed To Be Edited');
           redirect('admin/edit_item');
         }
         else
         {
           // After Image Get Uploaded, Adjust The Image Field On The Database
           $success_data['image_name'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
           $success_data['id'] = $product_id;
           $update = $this->Product_model->adjust_image($success_data);

           if($update) {
             $this->session->set_flashdata('success_edit_item', 'The Item Is Successfully Edited');
             redirect('admin/edit_item');
           }

         }
       }
     }
   }
```

And On the admin_edit_item view
 
here is the form head

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/edit_item/<?php echo $products->id; ?>">
```

As you can see, I already set the action on the form,
So, it should work.
I mean, even though I get that error, when I reload the database,
the data has been updated according to the edited data that I change.
But still I get that error.
I tried to find the bug, but have no luck.

Comment: why am I seeing more and more banner effects lately?

Comment: Does my question bad or something ?

Comment: Where's the `edit_item` call? From the error message you aren't passing it an id.

Comment: please don't highlight everything, just the error message will do.

Comment: I call it from the view , on that form where i wrote the action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/edit_item/<?php echo $products->id; ?>"

Comment: Sounds like you have `edit_item()` not `edit_item(somevalue)`. Your function doesn't have a default value set.

Comment: Shouldn't that <?php echo $products->id; ?> get passed when I submit using form ?

Comment: Please learn the difference between base_url and site_url, and also, why not use form_open ?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is telling you that `$products->id` is not being passed. I cannot tell why not... looks like it should.

Note this is a **warning** not a **fatal error** which means that the method `edit_item($id)` will still run. Why it works is not clear mostly because you do not share the code for `Product_model->update_item()` which I assume is where the db is updated. (How does `update_item()` know which item to update???)

Because of this line of code

```
$product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
```

It appears that the "product_id" value is a form field.

Perhaps using the above code at the top of the method to get the value instead of trying to pass it to the method via URL will help solve your problem.

I suggest you rewrite your form html (without the product_id) as follows

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
  action="<?php echo base_url('admin/edit_item'); ?>">
```

The above makes better use of `base_url()` ([documentation here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url).) and is easier to read.

If you insist on passing the data via URL you could do this

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
  action="<?php echo base_url("admin/edit_item/{$products->id}"); ?>">
```

Comment: Actually, after I got a sleep, I found the solution,
`redirect('admin/edit_item');`
I should have add the $id at the end of it
`redirect('admin/edit_item/'.$id);`